# Fetch more than 2147483647 record from Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I inherited a Cassandra database with years of data in it. I was tasked to delete all records older than 2 years. I don't know how many rows the table contains, but it is a lot.

The table structure is this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  key1 bigint,
  key2 text,
  "timestamp" timestamp,
  some more columns,
  PRIMARY KEY ((key1, key2), "timestamp")
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("timestamp" DESC);
```

Since `key1` and `key2` are partition keys, I cannot simply delete everything with a `timestamp` < 2 years. You would need to do this per partition key.

So I went ahead and created a small tool in Java based on the async paging pattern described in the manual: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.11/manual/core/paging/

I do a `SELECT DISTINCT key1, key2 from my_table;`, iterate over the keys, delete rows for those keys older than 2 years, fetch the next page and repeat.

After a few hours, the tool completes and reports it has modified the rows of 2147483647 partitioning keys. That is exactly 2^32-1, the maximum of a signed 32-bit integer. This is probably some limit in Cassandra, because having exact that amount of keys is improbable.

My questions:

- How can I fetch ALL of the table?
- Is 2147483647 some (configurable) limit and why?

The other strategy would be to start a new table, use a TTL and write to both tables until two years have passed. But I would like to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at ScyllaDB - Scylla is a Cassandra compatible database.

There is indeed a limitation in Cassandra paging - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14683 and it is not yet fixed.

What you can try and do is use the last token returned and continue paging from that state

```
select distinct token (key1,key2), key1,key2 from my_table ;
```

and then when the paging ended you would change the query and use the last returned token (as an example)

```
select distinct token (key1,key2), key1,key2 from my_table where token(key1,key2) >= -3748018335291956378;
```

(you need to reiterate with >= since multiple pairs maybe mapped to the same token)

PS: Scylla has uplifted this limitation (https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/5101) so we are bound by 2^64 -1